# How to use LruBitmapPool in Glide?

Tags: android, listview, android-glide

I am using **Glide** for displaying images in a listview.
How can I use **LruBitmapPool** to reduce GC (Garbage Collection)?
There is no sample around.

Glide Page :
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

Glide uses the LruBitmapPool automatically so you don't normally need to worry about it. It looks like you posted an issue on Glide's Github page, so let's follow up there: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/326.